# Attach javaagent to an application on Glassfish v3.x

Tags: java, glassfish, agent

I want to attach javaagent to my web application written in java on Glassfish server. I have read [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/glassfish-installation-for-java) and did it via this piece of code:

```
-javaagent:C:/Users/myname/desktop/myagent.jar
```

but the problem is that the agent is set to glassfish server and not to the application. Is there any way to set javaagent to one application on glassfish server?